# Can Domain name and host computer name be same

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory, windows-authentication

Recently I was trying to find answer to question "How to determine if current logged in user is part of domain or not"

On Stackoverflow I found pretty decent answers for the above which involved usage of

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

But I also see a simple solution saying

```
System.Environment.UserDomainName; - gives name of the current user's domain name.
System.Environment.MachineName;    - gives name of the machine.
```

If above two are not the same means the user is part of domain returned by UserDomainName

Fair enough, also confirmed by this link from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx)

Now the question is what if the "Domain name" and "Machine name" are identical?
or
Is it possible that a machine with the exact same name as domain name can join the domain?

If this is true, is there any possibilities to counter check this by adding something to this simple solution

Comment: Well if you are running your code on the domain-controller it could be the same.

Comment: There is not requirement the PDC (nor any BDC) have the same name as the domain.  But nothing stopping a computer from having the name of the domain that I know of.

Comment: only in domain controller domain name and machine name is same.

Comment: I am still in a discussion with dilemma, anyone who can make sure of this? @Karl-JohanSjögren - No for this case the code will not run on the domain controller machine.

Comment: Actually Windows doesn't allow you to add a computer to a domain if their names are the same. And you'll get different errors trying to overcome this limitation with still no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you the current logged on user does not have a distingished name if he or she isn't logged on to a domain. Use [GetUserNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT` type `NameFullyQualifiedDN` (1).

If you get a value back then you know the current user is logged on to a domain. Though, Calling this function might block your program unexpectedly for a period of time. You probably want to call this function in a asynchronous fashion as it might atempt to connect to some Active Directory service and just eventually fail or timeout.

An yet more resilient way to accomplish this would be to look up the account SID and check whether the `EqualPrefixSid` can compare it with the machine. If this is the case, then you know the current account is local to the machine (i.e. not in a domain). This does not involve crossing the network and waiting for a timeout, so it's a more direct approach. Interestingly, it also implies that if the machine name is the same as the user domain, Windows would have to assume that the domain you want to logon on to is the local machine and it should therefore be almost impossible to logon to the actual domain if the machine name really is the same as the domain.